# QtCreator Action on a video while in FullScreen

Tags: c++, qt, video, qt5

I am trying to develop a little video player with Qt by using QMediaPlayer and QVideoWidget (amongst others).
One of the features is to be capable of playing and pausing the video by using the spacebar Key. It works very well into the main window but when I set the Video Widget to be fullscreen by double-clicking it, the spacebar shortcut doesn't work.

The spacebar event implementation is generated into my MainWindow (inherits of QMainWindow) class while videowidget's fullscreen settings are handled into my VideoWidget class which inherits of QVideoWidget.

Is there any way to set the action of the QMediaPlayer to the fullscreen video widget?

Answer (score 0):

@Vinks I hope by override the

> bool event(QEvent *ipEvent ) override;

method on your class you can control the Keypress events and double click events.

Comment: I use the keyPressEvent method from QWidget and I override it into my class, the problem here is that the spacebar button has no effect on the video widget when the widget is set to fullscreen. 
The doubleclick works to quit the fullscreen because it is declared into the Video Widget class. On the opposite, the spacebar event is declared on the Main Window class which contains my Video Widget but I think with this declaration, play signal from QMediaPlayer doesn't work when Video is set to fullscreen